# How to get x and y of button from FOR loop in Android

Tags: android

In my case, I have a menu in which user can Select the tittle from menu that  he want and automatic scroll to the position which user selected.So, I need to retrieve X,Y of tittle but I cannot retrieve as well , all the X Y of tittle are same.

PFB my Source code:

```
//Size = 3 in my case

for (int i = 0; i < ArrayChpTittle.size(); i++) {
                          btnPage = new Button(getApplicationContext());
                          btnPage.setId(i);
                          btnPage.setText(ArrayChpTittle.get(i).toString());


                                //WebView 
                                wv_chpStory = new WebView(getApplicationContext());
                                wv_chpStory.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                                wv_chpStory.loadDataWithBaseURL(null,
                                        "<style>img{display: inline; height: auto !important; width:100%; max-width: 100%;}</style>"
                                                + ArrayChpStory.get(i).toString(),
                                        "text/html", "utf-8", null);



                                LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llstory);
                                linearLayout.addView(btnPage);
                                linearLayout.addView(wv_chpStory);



                                ArrayList<String> ArrayBtnX = new ArrayList<String>();
                                ArrayBtnX.add(String.valueOf(btnPage.getX()));

                                for (String data : ArrayBtnX){
                                    Log.i("ArrayBtnX: ", data);
                                }

 }
```

Output:

```
 I/ArrayBtnX:: 0.0

 I/ArrayBtnX:: 0.0

 I/ArrayBtnX:: 0.0
```

All the button X are equal.Why? Any solution for me.Thank alot guys

Answer (score 1):

You can get the Coordinates by this,

```
Point point = getPointOfView(button);
Log.d(TAG, "view point x,y (" + point.x + ", " + point.y + ")");

private Point getPointOfView(View view) {
    int[] location = new int[2];
    view.getLocationInWindow(location);
    return new Point(location[0], location[1]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In android ,ViewGroup do not layout their children immediately.You have to wait for actual measurement of the view.
You have to use ViewTreeObserver. Usually the `OnGlobalLayoutListener` is what you want for getting the measurement, so the code in the listener will be called after the layout phase, so the measurements are ready.

```
btnPage.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                btnPage.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
                ArrayBtnX.add(String.valueOf(btnPage.getX()));
            }
        });
```

The listener will be immediately removed otherwise it will fire on every layout event.